# Already installed Ansible on OSX via PIP but still not found

Tags: python, macos, pip, ansible

I already installed `ansible` via `pip` but when I run `ansible` via the command line it says command still not found.

I also looked for the `/etc/ansible/hosts` file but it seems that it's not found.

Am I missing something?

#### EDIT

Commands I ran:
`sudo pip install ansible`
and response was
`Successfully installed ansible paramiko jinja2 PyYAML pycrypto ecdsa MarkupSafe`

I also have `Xcode` installed.

I can also see that `ansible` is indeed installed in `pip list`:

> ansible (2.0.2.0)
> ecdsa (0.13)
> Jinja2 (2.8)
> MarkupSafe (0.23)
> mysql-utilities (1.5.3)
> paramiko (1.16.0)
> pip (1.5.6)
> pycrypto (2.6.1)
> PyYAML (3.11)
> setuptools (20.9.0)
> vboxapi (1.0)
> wsgiref (0.1.2)

### UPDATE

So fixed my own problem. I had `Python` installed before and had another instance installed when I installed `Xcode`. So what I did is removed my previous installation and just used the `Python` that came with `Xcode`. It was confusing at first because they both have the same version so I wasn't sure which was which.

## Follow Up Question:

So I have an existing `/usr/bin/python` installed but I'm not sure where this is sourced from. Because this doesn't seem like a symbolic link but actually an executable. Anyone has an idea? Is this from the `/System/` or from `/Library/`?

Comment: Are you sure it completed successfully? Did you run the pip install with `sudo`? This is necessary as it writes to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible`. Look for a message like `error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible': Permission denied` in the output `~/Library/Logs/pip.log`.

Comment: I did sudo as per instruction.

Comment: I even got `Successfully installed ansible paramiko jinja2 PyYAML pycrypto ecdsa MarkupSafe`

Comment: If you have Homebrew installed, you might also have installed Python to `/usr/local`. Run `which python` and `which pip` to see the active interpreter. It may have installed ansible there instead of in the system dir, and it may or may not be on your path.

Comment: I don't have `homebrew` installed. I have 3 versions for `python` installed: 2.5,2.6, and 2.7 probably it was maintained by `Xcode`. But I made sure that I was using the latest and when I ran `which python` I do in fact use 2.7.

Comment: Read the installation results for ansible in `~/Library/Logs/pip.log` and see exactly where it was installed. Then verify that the binary folder is on your path. The `/etc/ansible/hosts` file isn't necessarily created for you by default. But the `ansible` command should be found, provided the install succeeded and the path is set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So fixed my own problem. I had `Python` installed before and had another instance installed when I installed `Xcode`. So what I did is removed my previous installation and just used the `Python` that came with `Xcode`. It was confusing at first because they both have the same version so I wasn't sure which was which.

These [steps](https://valdhaus.co/writings/ansible-mac-osx/) helped me.